# Запреты копирования и перемещения мьютекса из стандартной библиотеки

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, оператор-присваивания, конструктор-копирования

В исходниках файла  не могу найти запрета перемещающих операций. Копирующие явно запрещены посредством `= delete`, причем так

```
_Mutex_base(const _Mutex_base&) = delete;
_Mutex_base& operator=(const _Mutex_base&) = delete;
```

и так:

```
mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
mutex& operator=(const mutex&) = delete;
```

Зачем два раза это нужно? Да, и почему нет запрета перемещения? Он какой-то неявный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявление собственного копирующего / перемещающего конструктора / оператора присваивания предотвращает генерацию других вариантов.

В приведенных кусках кода запрещено не два раза, а для двух различных классов.

Comment: Так понял, запрет некоторых также предотвращает?

Comment: Для двух различных классов, но один наследуется от другого - тут нет излишества?

Comment: @Jenssen Да, запрет некоторых тоже предотвращает. И нет, это не излишество. Скорее упрощение. Если бы они запретили прочие варианты явно, то компилятор выдавал бы более толковое сообщение.

Comment: @VTT, извините, не могли бы Вы объяснить, почему это не стоит считать "излишеством" - повторный запрет на использование конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания?

Comment: @isnullxbh Во-первых это не повторный запрет, а *явный* запрет. Во вторых, такой явный запрет предотвращает появление хрупкости в коде, ведь если не будет явного запрета, то когда когда-нибудь базовый класс изменят, реализовав конструкторы копирования, или заменят на другой класс, то дочерний класс без предупреждения тоже станет копируемым.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо за объяснение! :)